# Row reduction and how to find unknown

Tags: matrices

So I have been struggling with this problem for about two hours now. I have these equations:

[image]

And I'm asked to find out for which values of k do we have

a) No soultions
b) A unique solution
c) Infinitely many solutions

I have seen a similar problem where they first find the reduced row echelon form of the expanded matrix, but I'm stuck.

[image]

I have tried a lot of different things now, for example change the order of the equations. But I always get stuck when I come to the last equation where I'm trying to change the second "element" in the row to a $0$. Does anyone have some good tips?

Comment: Are you trying to solve for k with knowledge that the left $3\times 3$ is augmented with the 4th column?

Comment: @Countable. I'm sorry, I should have written the problem more detailed. I will edit the post now so that it's easier to understand what I'm asking about.

Comment: I am going to use the fact that if k is s.t. there is at least one solution, then we can forcibly apply the row operations like we normally do and "solve" for k that way, I have to take care of some other things, so I will post a solution probably later today.

Comment: @Thank you so much for taking the time helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have this, hopefully it is helpful:

Case (I) $k\in \{3,-5\}$, in which case I am getting a free variable (you can check this for $k = 3$ and $k = -5$ individually via standard gaussian elimination), so infinitely many solutions.

Case (II) $k = -\frac{1}{2}$, in which case I am getting a unique solution (you can check this via standard gaussian elimination).

Case (III) $k\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{3,-5, -\frac{1}{2}\}$. I used substitution to solve for $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$ in terms of k as follows:

We have

\begin{equation}
x_1 = 2 -kx_2 + x_3 \text{ (by Eq.1)}\\
4 - (2k+ 1)x_2+ (2+k)x_3 = 5 \text{ (by the above line and Eq.2)}\\
- (2k+ 1)x_2+ (2+k)x_3 = 1\\
x_2 = \frac{1 - (2+k)x_3}{-(2k+1)}
\end{equation}
substitute this into Eq.3 to solve for $x_3$, viz:

\begin{equation}
[2 -kx_2 + x_3] + 10[\frac{1 - (2+k)x_3}{-(2k+1)}] -6x_3 = 1\\
[2 -k\frac{1 - (2+k)x_3}{-(2k+1)} + x_3] + 10[\frac{1 - (2+k)x_3}{-(2k+1)}] -6x_3 = 1\\
(-k+10)\frac{1 - (2+k)x_3}{-(2k+1)}-5x_3 = -1\\
\frac{-k+10}{-(2k+1)} - \frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{-(2k+1)}x_3 - 5x_3 = -1\\
\bigg[\frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{2k+1} - 5\bigg]x_3 = -1 - \frac{10-k}{-(2k+1)}\\
x_3 = \frac{-1 - \frac{10-k}{-(2k+1)}}{\bigg[\frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{2k+1} - 5\bigg]}
\end{equation}

Plugging this into the last line of the first block of equations obtains:

\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{1 - (2+k)}{-(2k+1)}\frac{-1 - \frac{10-k}{-(2k+1)}}{\bigg[\frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{2k+1} - 5\bigg]}
\end{equation}

Plugging our expressions for $x_2$ and $x_3$ into $x_1 = 2 -kx_2 + x_3$ gives:

\begin{equation}
x_1 = 2 - k\frac{1 - (2+k)}{-(2k+1)}\frac{-1 - \frac{10-k}{-(2k+1)}}{\bigg[\frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{2k+1} - 5\bigg]} + \frac{-1 - \frac{10-k}{-(2k+1)}}{\bigg[\frac{(2+k)(-k+10)}{2k+1} - 5\bigg]}
\end{equation}

We can do this since $k \notin \{3,-5, -\frac{1}{2}\}$ (the roots of all of the denominators, when thought of as polynomials in k). So we have a unique solution in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I really appriecate your help. I spent some time reading properly through your answer before replying. I understand everything except case 3. You say that case 1 gives infinite many solutions, case 2 gives a unique solution. But I didn't understand what you meant by case 3. Is that the case for no solutions?

Comment: I believe it is a unique solution in case 3, if you plug in any value of k we have a unique $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ by my computations,  which is what it means to have a unique solution (unless I have an error somewhere, but it should all be good).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: No problem. ----